# cron job django on prod server - manage.py not found

Tags: python, django, cron

i am trying to setup a cron job in the server and i wrote this line in cron tab:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings_local PYTHONPATH=$HOME/django-locate:$HOME/locate/locate python manage.py testcommand
```

but i am getting in `var/mail/myname` the error saying that manage.py not found.

what am i doing wrong here?

this is my cronjob:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
args = "<test cron job>"
help = "writes locations from other server" 
def handle(self,*args,**options):
    self.stdout.write("cron job is running - it is just a test ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`manage.py` isn't in cron's current directory. Either change the current directory before running it, or provide the full path to the script.

Comment: how can i give full path to script? or which one is better, changing directory of cron or provide the full path to script?

Comment: Giving the full path is easier.

Comment: working like a charm. i did this: ``$HOME/path/to/project/manage.py``. thanks in tons